# REST API в качестве backend

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, backend

Хочу сделать мини соц сеть
Правильно ли если так делать:
Написать фронтенд на Vue js, NUXT А в качестве backend использовать api в качестве обработки данных, вывод постов, лайков, и т.д
Или как можно комбинировать Vue с backend, напишите свои варианты

Comment: Лучше всего использовать api это правильная практика. Совмещать vue и backend лучше не стоит. Один раз мне попался такой проект, там vue файлы были вперемешку с php и собирались они тоже непонятно как с помощью php :D Никто за такой проект браться не хотел

Comment: На счёт правильно или нет? То правильно разделение проекта на бэк и фронт. На счёт класть в одну папку нет пусть это будет отдельный проект так чтобы этот бекенд можно будет использовать для других целей. А php или что-то другое это выбирают исходя из рынка на сегодняшний день. Если вы не найдете специалиста на Кобол грубо говоря то зачем начинать такой проект

Comment: Идея разделение это всё таки микросервисы чтобы заменить любой кусок в нужный момент быстро

Answer (score 0):

Rest это шаблон проектирования. Данный шаблон могут реализовать почти все.

На счёт правильно или нет? То правильно разделение проекта на бэк и фронт. На счёт класть в одну папку нет пусть это будет отдельный проект так чтобы этот бекенд можно будет использовать для других целей. А php или что-то другое это выбирают исходя из рынка на сегодняшний день. Если вы не найдете специалиста на Кобол грубо говоря то зачем начинать такой проект.

Идея разделение это всё таки микросервисы чтобы заменить любой кусок в нужный момент быстро